# How to create a multirow table within a longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, multicolumn, multirow

Kindly review the code below and help me.

```
\begin{longtable}{| c | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | L{3cm} | }
            \hline
            \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
            \makecell{} & \makecell{Centrifugal \\ force}  & \makecell{Gravitational \\ force} & \makecell{Inclination} & \makecell{Vibration} & \makecell{Fluidization} & \makecell{Inertial \\ force} & \makecell{Other \\ Effects}\\
            \hline
            \endhead
           Size & \multirow{2}{*}{Cyclones} & Counter flow vertical air raise classifiers, Zig-Zag Classifiers & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & Cyclones, Rotating Wheel Air-Classifiers, High-Efficiency Separator, Turbo-air Classifier, Circulating air-classifiers. & &  \\
           \hline
           Density &  & alpha & echo & charlie & bravo &  & \\
          \hline
           Shape & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & &  \\
           \hline
           
        \end{longtable}
```

**I suggested this MWE since your example above is not compileable.** Starting with \documentclass{...} and defining a `\newcolumntype{L}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{| c | L{2cm} | L{2cm} | L{2cm} |L{2cm} | L{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | }
        \hline
    %   \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
        \makecell{} & \makecell{Centrifugal \\ force}  & \makecell{Gravitational \\ force} & \makecell{Inclination} & \makecell{Vibration} & \makecell{Fluidization} & \makecell{Inertial \\ force} & \makecell{Other \\ Effects}\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        Size & \multirow{2}{*}{Cyclones} & Counter flow vertical air raise classifiers, Zig-Zag Classifiers & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & Cyclones, Rotating Wheel Air-Classifiers, High-Efficiency Separator, Turbo-air Classifier, Circulating air-classifiers. & &  \\
        \hline
        Density &  & alpha & echo & charlie & bravo &  & \\
        \hline
        Shape & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. & &  \\
        \hline
        
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how the `L` column type is defined.

Comment: Is this the output you want to obtain?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk0cR.png If so, there is no need for `\multirow`. Remove this command and replace the `\hline` below it with `\cline{1-1} \cline{3-8}`

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear what is your problem (beside that table is to wide for fitting on pages). You may consider the following a wee bit changes of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, multirow}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{| c | *{7}{L{20mm}|} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!60}
    & \makecell{Centrifugal \\ force}  
        & \makecell{Gravitational \\ force} 
            & \makecell{Inclination} 
                & \makecell{Vibration} 
                    & \makecell{Fluidization} 
                        & \makecell{Inertial \\ force} 
                            & \makecell{Other \\ Effects}       \\
    \hline
\endhead
% table body
Size & \multirow[t]{12}{=}{Cyclones}
        & Counter flow vertical air raise classifiers, Zig-Zag Classifiers
            & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                    & Cyclones, Rotating Wheel Air-Classifiers, High-Efficiency Separator, Turbo-air Classifier, Circulating air-classifiers.
                        &   &   \\
   \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
Density 
    &   & \makecell{alpha} 
            & \makecell{echo}
                & \makecell{charlie} 
                    & \makecell{bravo}
                        &   &   \\
  \hline
Shape 
    & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. 
        & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. 
            & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. 
                & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. 
                    & These kind of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. 
                        &   &   \\
   \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps.

Comment: @user3454353, you can up-vote answer (instead to say "thank you", according to policy of this site), if you liked and even accept it, if it solve your problem on the best way (by click on on up-triangle and checkmark at top left side of answer. Accepting is important  information to other members of site, it inform them that question has good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you are looking for
[image: table]

I have used the `booktabs` package to typeset this table. Your question wasn't very clear, so I just tried what I felt was good.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{
        c 
        >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm} 
        >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}
        >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}
        >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}
        >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}
        >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}
        p{2cm}}\toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\scshape force} 
            & Inclination 
                & Vibration
                    & Fluidization 
                        & Other \\\cmidrule{2-4}
%
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Centrifugal} 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Gravitational}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Inertial} 
                    &&&& Effects \\\midrule
%
        Size 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cyclones} 
                & Counterflow vertical air raise classifiers, Zig-Zag Classifiers 
                    & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                        & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document. 
                            & Cyclones, Rotating Wheel Air-Classifiers, High-Efficiency Separator, Turbo-air Classifier, Circulating air-classifiers. 
                                & &  \\\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-6}
        Density 
            & & aplha
                & echo 
                    & charlie 
                        & bravo 
                            & & \\\midrule
        Shape 
            & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                    & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                        & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                            & These kinds of issues are mostly related to the PDF viewer, they will not appear in a print version of the document.
                                & &  \\\bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**tip**: avoid using vertical lines in tables `:)`

Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Currently, your table is more than 2 cm wider than the available space and therefore protrudes into the margin. You might want to address that by reducing the column widths accordingly. (`xltabular`'s `X` type column might come in handy for that.)